# How to create order for bundle product with rest api Magento2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, bundle, create-order

How to create order for bundle product with rest api Magento2 ?

I create an order using Rest Api for a simple product, but for a bundle product it does not work, any example can help me, thanks.

For this, I use this link

https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/salesOrderRepositoryV1SavePut

/rest/V1/orders/create

```
 "entity"=>
        [
            "base_currency_code"=>"USD",
            "base_discount_amount"=> 0,
            "base_grand_total"=> 120,
            "base_shipping_amount"=> 0,
            "base_subtotal"=> 120,
            "base_tax_amount"=>0,
            "customer_email"=> "test@test.test",
            "customer_firstname"=> "test",
            "customer_group_id"=> 1,
            "customer_id"=> 134,
            "customer_is_guest"=> 0,
            "customer_lastname"=> "test",
            "customer_note_notify"=> 1,
            "discount_amount"=> 0,
            "email_sent"=> 1,
            "coupon_code"=> "Test1",
            "discount_description"=> "Test1",
            "grand_total"=> 120,
            "is_virtual"=> 0,
            "order_currency_code"=> "USD",
            "shipping_amount"=> 0,
            "shipping_description"=> "Flat Rate - Fixed",
            "state"=> "new",
            "status"=> "pending",
            "store_currency_code"=> "USD",
            "store_id"=> 1,
            "store_name"=> "Main Website\nMain Website Store\n",
            "subtotal"=> 120,
            "subtotal_incl_tax"=> 120,
            "tax_amount"=> 0,
            "total_item_count"=> 1,
            "total_qty_ordered"=> 1,
            "weight"=> 0,
            "items" => [ [
                "base_discount_amount"=> 0,
                "base_original_price"=> 0,
                "base_price"=> 0,
                "base_price_incl_tax"=> 0,
                "base_row_invoiced"=> 0,
                "base_row_total"=> 0,
                "base_tax_amount"=> 0,
                "base_tax_invoiced"=> 0,
                "discount_amount"=> 0,
                "discount_percent"=> 0,
                "free_shipping"=> 0,
                "is_virtual"=> 0,
                "name"=> "Mixte tandem",
                "original_price"=> 0,
                "price"=> 0,
                "price_incl_tax"=> 0,
                "product_id"=> 8,
                "product_type"=> "bundle",
                "qty_ordered"=> 1,
                "row_total"=> 0,
                "row_total_incl_tax"=> 0,
                "sku"=> "Mixte Tandem",
                "store_id"=> 1,
                "product_option"=> [
                "extension_attributes"=> [
                    "bundle_options"=> [
                        [
                            "option_id"=> 3,
                            "option_qty"=> 3,
                            "option_selections"=> ["12","15","16"]
                        ], [
                            "option_id"=> 4,
                            "option_qty"=> 2,
                            "option_selections"=> ["13","14"]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ]
                ],
            ] ],
            "billing_address"=> [
                "address_type"=> "billing",
                "city"=> "Gyumri",
                "company"=> "Shooga",
                "country_id"=> "AM",
                "email"=> "test@test.test",
                "firstname"=> "test",
                "lastname"=> "test",
                "postcode"=> "30332",
                "region"=> "Shirak",
                "region_code"=> "SK",
                "region_id"=> 19,
                "street"=> [
                        "Street 1",
                        "Street 2"
                    ],
                "telephone"=> "12345688"
            ],
    "payment"=> [
            "method"=> "checkmo"
    ],
    "extension_attributes"=> [
            "shipping_assignments"=> [
            [
                "shipping"=> [
                "address"=> [
                    "address_type"=> "shipping",
                        "city"=> "Gyumri",
                        "company"=> "Shooga",
                        "country_id"=> "AM",
                        "email"=> "test@test.test",
                        "firstname"=> "test",
                        "lastname"=> "test",
                        "postcode"=> "30332",
                        "region"=> "Shirak",
                        "region_code"=> "SK",
                        "region_id"=> 19,
                        "street"=> [
                        "Street 1",
                        "Street 2"
                    ],
                        "telephone"=> "12345688"
                    ],
                    "method"=> "flatrate_flatrate"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
        ]
```

Now i have it in admin

[image]

but i need like this

[image]

Comment: explain "does not work" show us your payload and to what endpoint you are sending it

Comment: Philipp Sander, i updated my question

Comment: I need to show selected products too

Comment: but you are only sending 1 product...why do you expect more to show up

Comment: then what's the point of bundle_options in this code?

Comment: can you redirect me to the right solution ? thanks

Comment: @RobinioTor did you got any solution? could you help on the solution

Comment: @Bharath i done this task without rest api

Comment: @RobinioTor okay...is it possible for you to share sample code for that? or any instructions Please?

Comment: @Bharath Do you need for all customers through cron or for each customer through sessions (when the customer logs into his account)?

Comment: @RobinioTor well I'm actually trying to import orders from cron and when it missed we will import it from admin. So if you can provide me the cron part i will customize to my needs.

Comment: @Bharath i added the  code

Answer (score 0):

@Bharath, I don't know it will help you , but it works for me

```
namespace venodor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Product as ProductTaxClassSource;
class CreateCheckout extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $orders;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $_quoteRepository;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_customerFactory;


    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    array $data = []

)
{
$this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
$this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
$this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
$this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
$this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
$this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
$this->customerRepository = $customerRepositoryFactory->create();
$this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCustomerCollection()
       {
           return $this->_customerFactory->create();
       }

public function createOrder(){
           try {
               $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
               $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

                           $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
                           $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                           $customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection();
                           foreach ($customerCollection as $customerCollection) {
                            $customerId = $customerCollection->getId();

                            $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                            $getEmailCustomers = $customerData->getEmail();
                            $customer->loadByEmail($getEmailCustomers);

                            $checkCartExist = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
                            $checkCartExist->getAllVisibleItems();
                            if ($checkCartExist['entity_id']) {
                                $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customerId);

                                $assignCustomer= $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customer->getEntityId());
                                $quote->setCurrency();
                                $quote->assignCustomer($assignCustomer);
                                $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                                $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
                                $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
                                $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
                                $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
                                $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
                                $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
                                $quote->collectTotals();
                                $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

                            }
                            if (isset($order)) {

                                $order->setEmailSent(0);
                                $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
                                $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order->getId()); 
                            }
                        }


           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               echo $e->getMessage();
           }
       }


 }
```

Comment: Thank you..but I don't see that you were setting bundle product or its selection items to quote which is the actual problem, can you please add that. Appreciate your help for this

Comment: @Bharath Do you need to add a bundle product  to the cart?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..!

Answer (score 0):

@Bharath this step added to the cart, the former was how I created the order.

You must add to this code in the foreach where you can take the product id and the product qty of the place these  `$products_id = $jsonData['product_id'];  $products_count = $jsonData['product_count'];`
I hope this helps you

```
                $products_id = $jsonData['product_id'];
                $products_count = $jsonData['product_count'];
                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($products_id);
                $options = $objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Option')
                    ->getResourceCollection()
                    ->setProductIdFilter($products_id)
                    ->setPositionOrder();
                $options->joinValues($store_id);
                $typeInstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');
                $options = $_product->getOptions($products_id);
                $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($typeInstance->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product);
                $selectionProds = array_reduce($selections->getData(), function ($carry, $selection) {
                    if (!isset($carry[$selection['option_id']])) {
                        $carry[$selection['option_id']] = [];
                    }

                    $carry[$selection['option_id']][] = $selection['selection_id'];

                    return $carry;
                }, []);
                $selectionQty = array_reduce($selections->getData(), function ($carry, $selection) {
                    if (!isset($carry[$selection['option_id']])) {
                        $carry[$selection['option_id']] = [];
                    }

                    $carry[$selection['option_id']][] = $selection['selection_qty'];

                    return $carry;
                }, []);


                    $data = [
                        'qty' => $products_count,
                        'product' => $products_id,
                        'bundle_option' => $selectionProds
                    ];

                    $checkCartExist = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
                    $checkCartExist->getAllVisibleItems();

                    $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

                    $getEmailCustomers = $customerData->getEmail();
                    $request->setData($data);
                    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
                    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                    $customer->loadByEmail($getEmailCustomers);
                    if (!$checkCartExist['entity_id']) {
                        $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
                        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote

                    } else {

                        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customerId);
                    }
                    $quote->setStore($store);
                    $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customer->getEntityId());

                    $quote->setCurrency();
                    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
                    $quote->addProduct($_product, $request);
                    $quote->collectTotals();
                    $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
                    $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
                    $this->_sendemail->sendTransactionalEmail($getEmailCustomers);
```

And all the classes that I injected . here, there may be superfluous classes you may not need, you can simply remove them

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
    \AutoAddtocart\BundleAddtocart\Helper\Data $sendEmail,
    array $data = []

)
{
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_currency = $currency;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepositoryFactory->create();
    $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    $this->_sendemail = $sendEmail;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```